# Does iTunes Store always put sheen on 512x512 image when submitting iPhone app?

Tags: ios, app-store

I really don't like that sheen it puts on my image, does anyone know a way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

On [apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html), it is says:

> Create a 512 x 512 pixel version of your application icon for display in the App Store.[...] **There are no visual effects added to this version of your application icon.**

To not having shine of app icons, you have to set `UIPrerenderedIcon` key to your application’s `Info.plist` file